# \n (New Line) is replacing whole string when I use preg_replace function

Tags: php, regex

When I try

`$stg = preg_replace("/<PREPNAME>.*<\/PREP_ZIP>/s","",$stg);`

It properly work and it replace the text written in that function. And I get `$stg` is stripped and I get remaining string.

But when I try with `"\n"`, it empty the complete string.

```
$stg = preg_replace("/<PREPNAME>.*<\/PREP_ZIP>\n/s","",$stg);
```

I get `$stg` empty in second case.

Please help. Where I am missing ?

Example String :-

This is not an XML string. This is just a blob data that is stored in the database. While fetching this is just a string.

```
<T2_NASD_LAST_NAME1>ASDSADSA</T2_NASD_LAST_NAME1>\r\n    
<T2_NASD_FIRST_NAME1>SADASD</T2_NASD_FIRST_NAME1>\r\n    
<T2_SOC1>012345678</T2_SOC1>\r\n     
<T2_DOBM1>02</T2_DOBM1>\r\n  <T2_DOBD1>02</T2_DOBD1>\r\n     
<T2_DOBY1>1984</T2_DOBY1>\r\n    
<T2_NASD_LAST_NAME>ASDSADSA</T2_NASD_LAST_NAME>\r\n
<T2_NASD_FIRST_NAME>SADASD
</T2_NASD_FIRST_NAME>\r\n
<T2_NASD_MIDDLE_NAME>ASDA</T2_NASD_MIDDLE_NAME>\r\n
<T2_SOC>012345678</T2_SOC>\r\n<T2_ADR_ADRN>SADSADAS</T2_ADR_ADRN>\r\n
<T2_ADR_ADRA>DASD</T2_ADR_ADRA>\r\n<T2_ADR_ADRC>ASDSADSA</T2_ADR_ADRC>\r\n
<T2_ADR_ADRS>MI</T2_ADR_ADRS>\r\n<T2_ADR_ADRZ>11111</T2_ADR_ADRZ>\r\n
<T2_DOBM>02</T2_DOBM>\r\n<T2_DOBD>02</T2_DOBD>\r\n
<T2_DOBY>1984</T2_DOBY>\r\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<PREPFLAG>NONE</PREPFLAG>\n
<PREPNAME>AAAA</PREPNAME>\n
<PREPADDRESS>BBBB</PREPADDRESS>\n
<PREP_ZIP>1984</PREP_ZIP>
```

Comment: Can you give an example string, please.

Comment: Looks like you're manipulating xml with regexes. You should use a xml library like DOM or simplexml for that. BTW, you example string does not contain `<PREPNAME ...`

Comment: There's no `<prepname>` and no `</prep_zip>` in your example string, and using your RegExp works fine for me: the string isn't changed.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I have added the example string.

Comment: It's 2013. Don't parse XML with regexes.

Comment: $str is empty but  $stg .....haha

Comment: @Sahal Can not reproduce: http://3v4l.org/ThZ2b#v430

Comment: @JackManey, I know things are changed. But in the Legacy system we can't have JAVA in place for PHP :D. Its not easy to have a parser in all the places. Some places we should cop with what is there before.

Comment: You don't have put the \n in your example string

Comment: @Sahal - Who said anything about Java?! XML parsers exist for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You must add two \ before \n and use simple quotes

```
<?php 
$subject = <<<'LOD'
<T2_DOBY1>1984</T2_DOBY1>\r\n    
<T2_NASD_LAST_NAME>ASDSADSA</T2_NASD_LAST_NAME>\r\n
<T2_NASD_FIRST_NAME>SADASD
<PREP_ZIP>NONE</PREP_ZIP>\n
</T2_NASD_FIRST_NAME>\r\n
<T2_DOBY1>1984</T2_DOBY1>\r\n    
<T2_NASD_LAST_NAME>ASDSADSA</T2_NASD_LAST_NAME>\r\n
<T2_NASD_FIRST_NAME>SADASD
</T2_NASD_FIRST_NAME>\r\n
LOD;
$pattern = '~<PREP_ZIP>.*?</PREP_ZIP>\\\n~s';
echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace($pattern, "#!!!YOUHOU!!!#", $subject));;
```

Comment: Not sure why, it doesn't replace the string at all.